# retrieve values from NSUserDefault in iPhone after setting again

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsuserdefaults

In App delegate, I have following code:

```
NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *alrmTime = @"10:00 AM"; 
[pref setObject:alrmTime forKey:@"alarmTime"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

From here I am getting from App delegate User Daeault in Controller A using code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *tempAlarmTime = [defaults stringForKey:@"alarmTime"];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Remind At %@", tempAlarmTime];
```

Now, I need to set this userdefault in Controler B , For this m using this:

`NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [prefs setObject:mTimeIntervalSTR forKey:@"alarmTime"];
   [prefs synchronize];`

Now when I need to get this new value in Controller A its coming Null. Why this is happening, and how will I get new set value?

Comment: Are you trying to get different values from the 'alarmTime' key in controller A and B?

Comment: Yes its giving same result..its not setting 2nd time

Comment: A stupid question perhaps: are you sure that `mTimeIntervalSTR` in not nil?

Comment: thanks for your time Guys...it worked...I was not setting mTimeIntervalSTR properly.

Answer (score 0):

in Controler B use the following to change the userdefault value

```
NSString *timeString =[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alarmTime
    "]mutableCopy];

        timeString = mTimeIntervalSTR;

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:timeString
     forKey:@"alarmTime "]; 

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Comment: No this has not worked.I think I have to use NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification

Answer (score -1):

After adding a value, call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`.

Comment: Ya you're right, but he is asking question after resetting, so i assumed he is having problem after using the `pref setObject` in controller B.